# Cubase blocks other programs from recording audio

Tags: audio-recording, cubase

When I run cubase with the asio4all driver, I can no longer record audio with audacity. I used to record with audacity th playback from cubase but now I get an error message in audacity that I can't record because another application is using the program. If I exit cubase then other program can access the sound. I use an external USB soundcard (plexgear). Is there a resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I recall that Cubase has an option for this.

Find the 'Device Setup' window, select VST Audiobay and select ***"Release ASIO Driver in Background"***.  This should allow you to minimize Cubase and utilize your audio card with other software.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious why you are recording into an external program.
Instead of that you may just try to record into another submix track inside Cubasis.